# Minimum value is always showing as 0 in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;



public class Exercise16 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a sequence of positive integers");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_string = user_input.nextLine();
        boolean hasNegativeOne = user_string.contains("-1");

        if (hasNegativeOne){
            String[] sequence = user_string.split(" ");

            int[] numbers = new int[sequence.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length;i++) {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(sequence[i]);
            }


        // Method for getting the maximum value
            int max_value = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
                if (numbers[i] > max_value){
                    max_value = numbers[i];
                }
            }

        // Method for getting the minimum value
            int min_value = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
                if (numbers[i] < min_value){
                    min_value = numbers[i];
                }
            }


            System.out.println("The maximum value is: " +max_value);
            System.out.println("The minimum value is: " +min_value);


        }

    }
}
```

Hi everyone, I am developing a program where the user inputs a sequence of positive integers. My program is supposed to display the maximum and minimum value. However, whenever I run the program, the minimum value is always set as 0, even if the inputted sequence doesn't contain a 0. How can I change this? Also, I included the "if (numbers[i] > -1){" line as my program isn't allowed to accept negative numbers. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

min_value starts at 0. You can't accept negative numbers. Then you try to say:

```
if(number[i] < min_value)
```

If you can't accept negative numbers no number will be less than 0.

Comment: wow I feel so stupid for not noticing that, I just kept looking at the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialize your minimum to something like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to initially set you `max_value` and `min_value` to `numbers[0]`. In this case you will correctly process both cases as your default value is also valid as it is a part of user input. If there will be elements greater than (or less than) first element of array you will reassign it

```
if (numbers.length != 0) {
    int max_value = numbers[0];
    int min_value = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int num = numbers[i];
        if (num > max_value) {
            max_value = num;
        }
        if (num < min_value) {
            min_value = num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The maximum value is: " + max_value);
    System.out.println("The minimum value is: " + min_value);
} else {
    // process empty user input
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but you should check if the array has a length > 0

Comment: @MistahFiggins thanks for your comment, edited my answer